# How can I increase the drag speed of button?

Tags: ios, drag-and-drop, uibutton

I am making a a dragging code in which I am dragging button, now the problem is when I start dragging it slowly it works cool, but when I started dragging it bit fast its not working good cause button dropped during drag.

How can I increase the speed of drag?

```
- (void)wasDragged:(UIButton*)button withEvent:(UIEvent*)event{
    CGPoint previousLocation;
    CGPoint location;
    UITouch *touch = [[event touchesForView:button] anyObject];
    previousLocation = [touch previousLocationInView:button];
    location = [touch locationInView:button];
    CGFloat delta_x = location.x - previousLocation.x;
    CGFloat delta_y = location.y - previousLocation.y;
    button.center = CGPointMake(button.center.x + delta_x,button.center.y + delta_y);
}
```

Comment: What does “button left during drag” mean?  How are you arranging for `wasDragging:withEvent:` to be called?

Comment: dropped during drag!
i made a custom keyboard and on its buttons i called a selector which calls this selector. 
[a1 addTarget:self action:@selector(wasDragged:withEvent:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];

Answer (score 0):

simply you can just adjust the delta

```
CGFloat delta_x = location.x - previousLocation.x;
CGFloat delta_y = location.y - previousLocation.y;

delta_x *= 1.5; //the factor of the speed
delta_y *= 1.5;

button.center = CGPointMake(button.center.x + delta_x,button.center.y + delta_y);
```

Comment: thank you it worked! but now having another problem its missing the button means when i start dragging the button goes faster then finger.

Comment: don't really understand your means,  you want your finger's speed as the same as the button's?

Comment: means i started dragging button with my finger on ipad.. i am doing it in normal speed but the button moves a step ahead from finger.

Comment: isn't that speed increased?  i'm confused :)

Comment: yes speed increased! but the problem is the speed of drag and the speed of button is not same, button moves faster than the speed of drag! hope you understand now?

Comment: i see...  so you want increase the speed of the finger dragging? by code?

Comment: yes! speed of drag and speed of button should be same but i need to drag it fast and smooth!

Comment: i'm confused totally now, :)  you can increase your speed of dragging by your hand right?

Comment: lol.. man, right now according to my code i can drag button in normal speed v.comfortably but when i start dragging button bit faster the button dropped during drag, now after increasing delta_x,_y, the button is dragging faster than finger touch means button should be beneath the finger tip while dragging but after increaseing deltax,y button is moving ahead from finger tip while i am dragging upwards or downwards! now you should understand the problem dude!

Comment: "dropped" means the dragging is interrupted?   if you finger move a little bit faster?

Answer (score 0):

why you don't you just set button.center coordonates as location.x and location.y? beacause location.x and location.y are the coordonates of where your finger is, and there should be the center of button